# Unable to map a shared folder in a batch script scheduled using task scheduler on windows 2012

Tags: networking, task, directory, scheduler, shared

I have a batch script which tries to map a network folder to a drive (net use Z: \ComputerName\Sharefoldername). The batch script is scheduled to run on windows using task scheduler.  The script hangs when the following option is selected "Run whether user is logged on or not". It hangs in either case when "Do not store password" option is selected or unselected.

However the script runs successfully and network folder is mapped when the following option is selected "Run only when user is logged on".

The user running the batch script is a administrator on that machine. Also
following option is always selected "Run with highest privileges"

Answer (score 0):

This is a security measure by design in more recent versions of Windows. Mapping a drive is user/profile dependent. When selecting "Run whether user is logged on or not", the script with run in a non-interactive mode (session 0) since it is not running as any particular user.  This [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run/) explains it fairly well.

The script will definitely run successfully if there are no errors, but unfortunately, you'll be mapping the drive letter for a non-interactive session instead of the user intended for.  If you add a command that is not user dependent, for example **md c:\DirectoryTest**, you will see that it'll still create the folder "DirectoryTest" in the c: drive since creating a folder is not user/profile dependent.

I think your best bet might be adding your mapping as part of a login script, or using Group Policy if available.

Please be sure to mark your questions as answered if you have been successfully helped.